# SNMP with MS Azure Storage

Tags: azure, storage, snmp, polling

I have set up a Big Data Hadoop Cluster that stores and analyzes data from several polling machines. All of the machines are Linux based.

My polling machines collect metrics from cable modems via snmp protocol and then process the data using resolvers. The final output is in the following form:
kpi timestamp value tag1 tag2 tag3...
That is then being sent to OpenTSDB on my Hadoop Cluster. All of this is done using opentsdb-snmp tool every two hours.

What I want to do is sent the final output from polling machines to MS Azure Storage also. The problem is that MS Azure supports only http/https protocols and I am wondering how I can achieve this. 
So, the basic question is:
How to send data from snmp enabled machines to MS Azure Storage in the form 
kpi timestamp value tag1 tag2 tag3...

I appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for this, though it is not directly moving the SNMP logs to Azure but rather into a fileshare on azure:

**1**

Go to Storage Account blade on Azure portal:
Click on add File Share button:
Provide Name and Quota. Quota currently can be maximum 5 TiB:

**2**

Attach the Fileshare into a local machine to which you save the logs

Full documentation and step by step guide on Azure File share can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share

This Should get you going on your project.

Comment: I agree - don't be sending large amounts of data in bulk over SNMP, it's not a good protocol for that. Use the mechanisms provided by putting the data into files.